# Oracle 8.1.7: how to restore two databases in one instance?

Tags: oracle, oracle8i, oracle8

Good night! I've oracle 8.1.7 on RHEL 3 Update 4 (Taroon) and cold backups (all DB files) of two databases. How to restore this two databases with different SID's in one installed instance? Thank you.

Comment: Just curious... are you a time traveler from the past?  8.1??

Comment: Yes, it is serious - oracle 8.1.7. Why not?

Answer (score 1):

You can't do it. My best guess is to restore db #1, then export all data. Then restore db #2. Import #1's dump into #2.